# Error: Can't create table 'Goober.Employee' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I get this following error for some reason, and I know it has to do with the foreignkey I just added "UsesTruck" However I don't know WHAT it is I did wrong.. I have included only the tables I think are important for this issue.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
EmployeeID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
UsesTruck CHAR(20) NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (UsesTruck) REFERENCES Truck(LicensePlate),
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID));


CREATE TABLE Truck (
LicensePlate CHAR(20) NULL,
color VARCHAR(45) NULL,
capacity VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (LicensePlate));
CREATE TABLE Shifts (
ShiftTime VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ShiftTime));



CREATE TABLE Reservation (
ReservNum INT NOT NULL,
ReserveDate VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PickupTime VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
NumOfPassengers INT NULL,
sheduledTime VARCHAR(45) NULL,
ActualPickupTime VARCHAR(45),
ActualTime VARCHAR(45),
PricePaid VARCHAR(45),
DriverHourlyRate DECIMAL(7,2) NULL,
PassEmployeeHourlyRate DECIMAL (7,2) NULL,
DriverSalary VARCHAR(10),
PassEmployeeSalary VARCHAR(10),
Customer_CustomerID INT,
Truck_LicensePlate char(20) NULL,
Employee_EmployeeID_Driver INT,
Location_Address_Pickup VARCHAR(100),
Employee_EmployeeID_Passenger INT,
Location_Address_Drop VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (ReservNum),
FOREIGN KEY (Customer_CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer (CustomerID),
FOREIGN KEY (Truck_LicensePlate) REFERENCES Truck (LicensePlate),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_EmployeeID_Driver) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (Location_Address_Pickup) REFERENCES Location (Address),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_EmployeeID_Passenger) REFERENCES Employee    (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (Location_Address_Drop) REFERENCES Location (Address));
```

Comment: I got it all to work without the foreign keys in your Reservation table, then added one and it choked. Try making sure all the tables your FKs refer to already exist (obvious, I know) and double- and triple-check that the table and column names match case-sensitively, and that the data types are identical on both sides of the FK relationship.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-error-codes.html might be helpful.

There are some other questionable things about your schema, but that wasn't your question (-:  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run create Truck table firstly.